# How to show values of a select based on previous select using JHipster relationships?

Tags: angular, relationship, jhipster

**I want to show options of second select based of user select in previous select.**

I have three entities: Reservation, Building and Classroom.
[There are relationships between them on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOamZ.png)

So my target is when I select in `Reservation` entity some `Building`, I want to show in `Classroom` select only Classrooms related to selected Building.

---

When I get for example `Classroom id: 1` there's GET for this classroom:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "number": "105",
  "building": {
    "id": 2,
    "number": "45",
    "reservations": null
  },
  "reservations": null
}
```

So as you can see it's related to Building with id:2 and number: 45.

---

My HTML in JHipster/Angular for showing those two selects in `Reservation` is:

```
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="srsApp.reservation.building"
            for="field_building">Building</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="field_building" name="building" formControlName="building"
            [(ngModel)]="building">
            <option [ngValue]="null"></option>
            <option
              [ngValue]="buildingOption.id === editForm.get('building').value?.id ? editForm.get('building').value : buildingOption"
              *ngFor="let buildingOption of buildings; trackBy: trackBuildingById">{{ buildingOption.number }}</option>
          </select>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="srsApp.reservation.classRoom" for="field_classRoom">Class
            Room</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="field_classRoom" name="classRoom" formControlName="classRoom"
            [(ngModel)]="classroom">
            <option [ngValue]="null"></option>
            <option
              [ngValue]="classRoomOption.id === editForm.get('classRoom').value?.id ? editForm.get('classRoom').value : classRoomOption"
              *ngFor="let classRoomOption of classrooms; trackBy: trackClassRoomById">{{ classRoomOption.number }}
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

I think I have to change `*ngFor` somehow, but idk how. **Right now** *Building* select shows all buildings and *Classroom* select shows all classrooms.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following our discussion on gitter:

1/ You need first to create a method in `ClassRoom.service.ts`(assuming you use entities-filtering):

```
// in classRoom.service.ts

getClassRoomsByBuildingId(buildingId: number): Observable<EntityArrayResponseType> {
        return this.http.get<IClassRoom[]>(`${This is the link of filter}/${buildingId}`, { observe: 'response' });
    }
```

2/ Add this code to `reservation-update.component.ts`:

```
getClassRoomByBuildingId(buildingId: any) {
        this.classRoomService.getClassRoomByBuildingId(buildingId).subscribe(res => {
            this.filteredClassRooms = res.body;
        });
    }
```

And finally in `reservation-update.component.html`:

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="srsApp.reservation.building" for="field_building">Building</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="field_building" name="building" formControlName="building" (change)="getClassRoomByBuildingId(building.id)" [(ngModel)]="buildingId">
            <option [ngValue]="null"></option>
            <option
              [ngValue]="buildingOption.id === editForm.get('building').value?.id ? editForm.get('building').value : buildingOption"
              *ngFor="let buildingOption of buildings; trackBy: trackBuildingById"
              >{{ buildingOption.number }}</option
            >
          </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="srsApp.reservation.classRoom" for="field_classRoom">Class Room</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="field_classRoom" name="classRoom" formControlName="classRoom" [(ngModel)]="classRoomId">
            <option [ngValue]="null"></option>
            <option [ngValue]="classRoom.id === editForm.get('classRoom').value?.id ? editForm.get('classRoom').value : classRoom" *ngFor="let classRoom of filteredClassRooms"
              >{{ classRoom.number }}
            </option>
   </select>
 </div>
```